# What does "arms" stand for in hotel names?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Sunset arms apts", "Hacienda Arms Apartments", "Windsor Arms Apartments", "Robot arms" (Futurama) - what are all those "arms"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In England hotels and pubs are often named after the heraldic 'coats of arms' belonging to royal or noble families. Plenty of pubs are called 'The King's Arms'. The practice seems to have spread across the Atlantic. Here is the heraldic coat of arms of the United Kingdom, used by the reigning monarch:

[image]

Comment: In some cases, such as the Futurama "Robot Arms", there is a deliberate pun. And in cases like "Sunset Arms Apartments" it is likely that there is no actual coat of arms, the apartment owner is just liked how the names sounds like an old pub.

Comment: >"sounds like an old pub" - haha, now I see! Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: To give slightly more background: historically (when much of the population was illiterate) shops and businesses were identified by a visual sign hanging outside the shop. Thus 'The Kings Arms' is the pub whose sign is a painting of the King's heraldic crest. "The Crown" probably had a (painting of) a crown hanging above the door. Etc etc.